# Can one hold IP anonymously?

Tags: united-states, copyright, intellectual-property

Can a writer who wants to maintain his personal anonymity as a book's author publish the book in a manner that would allow him to maintain full control of the copyright and distribution without revealing his true name? Something like, IDK, assigning the copyright to a corporation with unlisted shareholders?

Comment: You mean like publishing your work as Mark Twain when your real name is Samuel Clemens?

Comment: @DaleM, pseudonym may be insufficient: in order to exercise control over IP, for example to challenge infringement, you would need to prove that you indeed are the author, and at that point your anonymity is gone.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch, yes, the top answer to that question answers mine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can hold a copyright anonymously, and you don't have to go to all that trouble to do so.

Copyright protection begins at the moment an original work is fixed in a tangible medium. Once an author puts pen to paper, everything he writes is protected by copyright. He doesn't need to register the copyright or reveal his identity to anyone.

So Miles Taylor can anonymously write [A Warning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Warning_(book)), and he has full copyright protection by the time he finishes his first sentence. The actual work of publishing and distributing a book is highly impractical for a person who wants to maintain perfect anonymity, but Taylor could, theoretically, have chosen to simply print everything at Kinko's and surreptitiously drop copies off at coffee shops.

But major publishing houses understand that there is sometimes a need to maintain this kind of anonymity, and they will have procedures in place to accommodate authors who can't or won't reveal their identities.

Other types of IP operate under different rules, though. Trademark and patent protection, for instance, have more meaningful registration requirements, so an anonymous holder would be more likely go through the process you described to enforce those rights.

Comment: if all you do is publish anonymously or under an assumed name, how do you exercise any control over the publication without revealing your identity? Suppose you published "A Warning", then, in order to rein in the impact, a random Tea Party member announces that he was the author, that the publication is a lie he made up in a drunken stupor, and he takes it all back. How do you challenge that without revealing yourself? You would need to establish yourself as the copyright holder, and at that point your anonymity is gone.

Comment: That's sort of a separate question, as the fake author wouldn't be infringing on your copyright in any way. You might attempt some kind of defamation lawsuit or something; it's possible a court would allow you to proceed anonymously, but you'd probably lose the overall case, as people are allowed to lie about this sort of thing. Alternatively, you might just anonymously publish additional material explaining that the fake author is a fake.

Comment: That is often taken care of by the publisher.